# fpdf getStringHeight equivalent to getStringWidth

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to implement (in PHP using **fpdf**, https://www.fpdf.org) a `getStringHeight($string)` method, giving me back the height in pixel of the passed string
**fpdf** has the very useful `getStringWidth` method but, even looking into the source code, I couldn't find anything like `getStringHeight`.

The only possible idea that I have, is that I would render it somewhere, and then I would check in the bitmap itself when I see some pixels... With something like this (with some more ifs...):

```
y = yCoordinateOfTheString
while thisRowOfPixelsIsTotallyEmpty(y)
  ++y
start = y
while thereIsAtLeastOnePixelInThisRow(y)
  ++y
end = y
height = end - start + 1
```

Of course, this would be crazy inefficient, so... Is there another way? Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with fpdf, but typically the line height will be derived from the size of the font. String width functions are required since the the actual width depends on the text with proportional fonts.

Comment: The height of the FONT, yes, it's the size. But for example the height of the character ',' is way different than the character 'F'. I need the height of a character to vertically-center some text at pixel level, not at font level.

Comment: For SVG/PDF packages I have used that didn't offer a "height" function (outside PHP) - I have printed a carriage return and calculated the difference in the Y cursor (not sure if that helps here). You might find that it is always a fixed multiple of the font size. Hence you could skip the calculation afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

GetStringWidth() gives you the width of the output as if it were all on one line, but the actual output will naturally split into multiiple lines where the right margin intercepts. So take GetPageWidth(), minus off the left and right margins, and then divide your GetStringWidth() by this figure to determine the number of lines needed. Multiply the ceil() of this by whatever line height you're about to pass to Write() and this should equal the output height.

If you're not not outputting from the left of the page though then you'll want to add that indentation on to GetStringWidth() to account for the potential extra line needed.

http://www.fpdf.org/ for details on each of these functions.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 14);

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean non risus porta tortor sodales aliquet. Cras efficitur, purus ut molestie ultrices, eros urna egestas lacus, vel porttitor ante neque in est. Aliquam gravida metus enim, ut dignissim risus mattis eget. Aliquam accumsan lobortis elit molestie scelerisque.';
$singleLineWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($string);
$numberLines = ceil(($pdf->GetX() + $singleLineWidth) / ($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20)); // 20 accounts for the 10mm default margins
$lineHeight = 8;
$heightOfOutput = $numberLines * $lineHeight;

// Now use $heightOfOutput to, for example, determine if a page break is needed before output
if($pdf->GetY() > $pdf->GetPageHeight() - $heightOfOutput)
    $pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write($lineHeight, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your question, if you're only actually using FPDF for its GetStringWidth() method and you're not actually trying to output a PDF, you probably just want imagettfbbox() really.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php